# Installing gota package in go workspace

Tags: go, workspace, gopath, gota

I'm writing this away from my code so fingers crossed.

I've recently started learning Go from a Python background. I've set up my workspace (Linux Mint OS) so:

GOPATH=$HOME/go
GOROOT=/usr/local/go

Where under $HOME i have a dir called go and 3 subdirs called src, bin and pkg.

I wanted to mess around with some dataframes (I use pandas a lot in Python) so I tried to install gota from github. Only their recommended install command:

```
go get -u github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe
go get -u github.com/kniren/gota/series
```

returns an error saying it could find the package in GOPATH or GOROOT. To me this is strange as go get seems like the equivalent to pip install and shouldn't be looking in my path but rather at the URL. I managed to get some files to install but using goget and the github URL of the project:

```
go get github.com/go-gota/gota/dataframe
go get github.com/go-gota/gota/series
```

and this built some files under a gonum.org directory in my src dir and a linux_amd64 dir in my pkg directory. So far neither section have the expected path to the libraries and I can't find a suitable method to import. import statements look in gopath's src directory however I assume it should be looking in the pkg directory? Why is this and what's wrong with my env?

Comment: 1. Never, literally **never** set GOROOT. Never ever.

Comment: 2. The actual project is hosted at https://github.com/go-gota/gota so the import path is github.com/go-gota/gota.

Comment: 4. There are two modes in which Go works GOPATH mode (setting GO111Module=off) and modules mode (setting GO111MODULE=on). Choose on! GOPATH mode might be easier to start: In this mode source code is downloaded to src. The pkg folder is of zero interest to you; it is managed by the go tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of the repository must have migrated to a different repository.

The official repository of these packages is: [github.com/go-gota/gota](https://github.com/go-gota/gota)

```
https://www.github.com/kniren/gota/dataframe
https://www.github.com/kniren/gota/series
```

These repositories do not exist, this is why your `go get` commands failed. In fact, trying to navigate to [github.com/kniren/gota](https://www.github.com/kniren/gota) redirects me to their official repository.